# Hibernate Implicit Naming Strategy is ignored when using multiple datasources

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, orm

According to the following tutorial, I created two configruation files for two database sources:  [Baeldung-JPA-Multiple-Databases](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases)

It works fine, but it seems that the implicit naming strategy is ignored. That means that an Entity `CustomerContact` is not mapped to a table `customer_contact`.

I tried to add the following two properties, but nothing changes:

```
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManager() {
    ...
    properties.put("hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy", "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy");
    properties.put("hibernate.naming.physical-strategy", "org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy");
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    ...
}
```

One solution would be to use the name attribute of the persistence annotations, like
`@Entity(name = "customer_contact")`, but I would like to avoid that and use the implicit mapping instead.

Comment: Check this post, the problem is really similar to yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509395/cant-set-jpa-naming-strategy-after-configuring-multiple-data-sources-spring-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found here: [Can't set JPA naming strategy after configuring multiple data sources (Spring 1.4.1 / Hibernate 5.x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509395/cant-set-jpa-naming-strategy-after-configuring-multiple-data-sources-spring-1)

The needed properties are:

```
props.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
props.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
```

Comment: as of hibernate 6.x; `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy` is dropped and  `CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy` is used.